# Keep state when navating using RouterLink in Angular

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, state, angular-router

I have the following link in my project that goes from a list of "Properties" to "Create property" form:

`<button mat-button routerLink="../create-property" id="btn-new-property">+ Add property</button>`

I use redux to manage my state and when I press on the link, I notice that the state of my application resets i.e. all the properties that were loaded are no longer there.

I am trying to understand what is the practice here?
a) Shall I reload the properties from the service every time when a hit the list of "Properties"?
b) Shall I be using something instead of RouterLink that keeps the state automatically?

I have looked at the suggestion in the documentation, which says that I can pass some state using `[state]` property on the link, but that seems weird that I would have to constantly pass the entire state from link to link.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that in the reducer I have not returned the state in the default case i.e.g

````
javascript
switch(action) {
//some cool reducers
default:
return state;

}```
````